# Do I have to use "FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY" or "LIMIT" when selecting an unique id in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, db2

I was wondering if I have to use the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` statement in DB2 or the `LIMIT` statement in MySQL if I query a unique id with an index from a table to increase the performance. Or does the sql provider already notice, that there will be only one result at maximum and stop the query, when the row was found?

Example query:
DB2: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`
MySQL: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1`

Does anybody have already thought about this?

Comment: In mylsq   The limit is applied  on the result of the select  .. so you have not performance improvement

Comment: And what about the `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`?

Comment: I'm not in db2  but  .. i think is the same  .. this kind of limit/fliter can applied  only on a result set  ..  and the performance are based on result set retrieving

Comment: If you already have an unique index on `id`, then normally the optimizer must know that such a query can't return more than one row. I if you don't have such an unique index on `id`, then it might be worth to help the optimizer with building better access plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both the `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` as well as `LIMIT` in Db2, check the [DB2 compatibility settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html).

If only one row is returned, it does not matter if that syntax is specified. However, if you or the system is not sure, then it is an extra safeguard. Depending on the optimizer settings (or mood or statistics or metadata), the additional syntax may help with performance. The reason is that the database system knows that only 1 row should be returned and it can optimize for that case.

If there is a unique index on **id**, then it should be obvious, but is there an index...?

Comment: Yeah, there is an index on that row. I edited the question. So, is there any need to specify the LIMIT statement?

Comment: My answer already includes it. No need, but I would do it anyway out of habit.

Comment: And when you enable support for LIMIT in Db2, you can use that shorter syntax

Answer (score 2):

In case the attribute is declared unique, I strongly advise against this practice for two reasons:

1. it does not increase performance in any way for a moder optimizer, but only increases the work of the SQL optimizer that has another clause to process,
2. (most important) it reduces the readibility of the statement for a maintainer of the code, since it can give the impression that the attribute is not unique, producing confusion about the query and the underlying table.